# Camel CXF Jaxrs service implementation class's methods are not executing

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb, cxfrs

I am confused with the behaviour of cxf rest web service with camel route file. I have noticed the control never go inside the implementing class of the rest service interface.

Following are the steps how i am writing the web service using cxf jaxrs and camel

1. i have create a interface.

   ```
   @Path("/licence")
   public interface LicenceThresholdService {
       @POST
       @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
       @Path("/userThresholdBreached")
       Boolean isUsersThresholdBreached(User user);
   }
   ```
2. Implementation class

   ```
   public class LicenceThresholdServiceImpl implements LicenceThresholdService {
       @Override
       public Boolean isUsersThresholdBreached(final OEMUser user) {
           System.out.println("inside threshold breched method");
           return Boolean.FALSE;
       }
    }
   ```
3. Create the cxf jaxrs server

   ```
   <beans ...
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       ...
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf 
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
       ...">
       <cxf:rsServer id="userProfileService"
           address="http://{{service.host}}:{{service.port}}/userProfile"
           serviceClass="com.jato.esb.service.licence.LicenceThresholdServiceImpl"
           loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
           <cxf:providers>
               <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
           </cxf:providers>
       </cxf:rsServer>
   </beans>
   ```
4. injected the cxf rsServer bean in camel route endpoint

   ```
   <from uri="cxfrs://bean://userProfileService" />
   ```

Now my problem is whenever i call this service, control never went inside `isUsersThresholdBreached` method of `LicenceThresholdServiceImpl` class. Because of this i am not able to fully leverage the cxf rest services.

I have tried the cxf rest service with Mule esb and Spring application file, i have noticed that control always went inside the implementation class also, but this is not the case with camel route. 
I am using the redhat fuse esb.

Please help me out for this issue, this is a serious concern for us to go with camel.

Answer (score 0):

The serviceClass you used just from mapping the REST request to a java method invocation, the invocation information will be passed into camel route. In this way we can provides more generic solution, can you don't need to use [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html) the send the message to camel route.